# Aliases from ~/.bashrc don't work until I run . ~/.bashrc

Tags: ubuntu, bashrc

My aliases from `~/.bashrc` don't work until I run `. ~/.bashrc`. I see

```
alias_xxx: command not found
```

I log in via SSH and I started a new ssh session after making changes to `.bashrc`.

`echo $SHELL` returns `/bin/bash`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/161249/bashrc-not-executed-when-opening-new-terminal

Answer (score 1):

Adding `source ~/.bashrc` line in bash_profile solved this issue.